# Algebras of double dual monad

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, monads

Let $k$ be a field (more genererally a commutative ring) and consider
the category of vector spaces (modules).
The double dual endofunctor has a structure of monad where

- the unit is
  $$
    \begin{align}
    \eta_V \colon V &\to V^{\vee \vee} \\
    v &\mapsto (\alpha \mapsto \alpha(v)),
    \end{align}
    $$
- and the multiplication is
  $$
    \begin{align}
    \mu_V \colon
     \underbrace{((((V \to k) \to k) \to k) \to k)}_{V^{\vee \vee \vee \vee}}
     &\to
     \underbrace{(V \to k) \to k}_{V^{\vee \vee}} \\
    \psi &\mapsto (\alpha \mapsto \psi(\eta_{V^{\vee}}(\alpha))).
    \end{align}
    $$

> **Question:** what is an Eilenberg-Moore algebra for this monad?

Going by definition, it is a pair $(V, \xi \colon V^{\vee \vee} \to V)$
where the structural morphism $\xi$ is compatible with
unit and multiplication.

---

Compatibility with unit says that
$$
\xi(\alpha \mapsto \alpha(v)) = v
$$
for every $v \in V$.

I have trouble with compatibility with multiplication
and in giving a description for the final structure.

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104777/what-are-the-algebras-for-the-double-dualization-monad).

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm new to monadic functors, the answer by Todd Trimble says that the category $\operatorname{Vect}^{\operatorname{op}}$ is equivalent to the category of algebras? Would this still hold over commutative rings? Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's wat the answer implies : the category of algebras is equivalent to $\mathbf{Vect}^{op}$. The proof requires that the ring $k$ is [self-injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Self-injective_rings), so it holds for fields but not for $\mathbb{Z}$, for example.